# starting mining with bitcoin core once installed

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

How do I start mining once installed and running?  I don't see the bitcoin balance changing at all.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin cannot reasonably be mined on commodity hardware, and Bitcoin Core does not include any functionality to mine by itself anymore. The profit would be orders of magnitude smaller than your electricity bill and wear and tear to your hardware.

If you want to mine BTC, you need specialized hardware (called ASICs).